# Textarea window same as Stack overflow window where user can write in bold and do indentation?

Tags: css, reactjs

Hi I have a requirement in which user will be able to write a Document like a contract.
User should be able to write in Block letters, use underline options and do some indentation while writing his/her document.
I am using ReactJS for the development.
I am not sure how we can achieve it using a text area or form.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use a WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) editors.
[react-dragt-wysiwyg](https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg) is a good example.

You might need to do some research to figure out

1. which editor fits your requirements
2. relatively easy to integrate into your system
3. doesn't slow down your site
4. looks reliable, i.e. the original authors are likely to keep supporting it

Comment: thanks @Tamas, you hit the bulls eye...that is exactly what i wanted